# How to error handling for cancel timeout in Axios React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am calling the invokeCardScreen and if response not return in 10 seconds, I am timing out in api.js in axios . It goes to error bock and displays canceled. How to do the try catch block in Invokecardscreen.

**Api.js**

```js
import Axios from "axios";
import { workingStart, workingEnd } from "./actions";
import { globals } from "./lib";

Axios.defaults.headers.post["Content-Type"] = "application/json";

function newAbortSignal(timeoutMs) {
  const abortController = new AbortController();
  setTimeout(() => abortController.abort(), timeoutMs || 0);
  return abortController.signal;
}

const restClient = Axios.create({
  baseURL: globals().apiUrl,
  headers: {},
  signal: newAbortSignal(10000), //Aborts request after 10 seconds
});

restClient.interceptors.request.use(
  (config) => {
    workingStart();
    return config;
  },
  (error) => {
    workingEnd();
    return Promise.reject(error);
  },
);

restClient.interceptors.response.use(
  (response) => {
    workingEnd();
    return response;
  },
  (error) => {
    alert(error.message);
    const response = error.response.data;
    alert(response);
    // console.log(error.message)
    if (error.message === "Network Error") {
      const errorObject = {
        error: true,
        message: "Network Error",
      };

      //throw error
      return Promise.reject(errorObject);
    }

    workingEnd();
    if (error.response !== null && 401 === error.response.status) {
      // handle error: inform user, go to login, etc
    }

    return Promise.reject(error);
  },
);

export default restClient;
```

**SendPostMessageToService.js**

```js
import restClient from "../Api";
import axios from "axios";

const SendPostMessageToService = (payload) => {
  const { url, Payload, headers } = payload;
  return restClient
    .post(url, Payload, headers)
    .then(function (response) {
      return response;
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      alert(error);
      console.log("errormessage", error);
      return error;
    });
};

export default SendPostMessageToService;
```

**invokeCardScreen.js**

```js
import React from "react";
import SendPostMessageToService from "./SendPostMessageToService";

const ErrorCodes = [101, 103];

export const invokeCardScreen = async (language, cards) => {
  const url =
    getCardScreenUrl() + "&timeout=30&noninteractive=false&lang=" + language;
  const headers = getHeaders();
  const dPayload = '[{"Name": "BTN_DECLINE"}]';
  console.log(
    "---------------------Invoke Wires fees Screen------------------",
  );
  const { data } = await SendPostMessageToService({
    url: url,
    Payload: Payload,
    headers: headers,
  });

  let userData = "";
  if (data) {
    if (data?.Error) {
      userData = {
        CardScreenState: {
          response: data.Error.Message,
        },
      };
    }

    if (data?.Error) {
      if (
        data !== null &&
        data.Error !== null &&
        data.Error.Code !== null &&
        ErrorCodes.indexOf(data.Error.Code) > -1
      ) {
        userData = {
          CardScreenState: {
            response: data.Error.Code,
          },
        };
      }
    }

    if (data?.Event) {
      if (
        data !== null &&
        data.Event !== null &&
        data.Event.FieldName !== null
      ) {
        userData = {
          CardScreenState: {
            response: data.Event.FieldName,
          },
        };
      }
    }
  }

  if (data?.error === "canceled") {
    alert(90);
    userData = {
      CardScreenState: {
        error: "cancelled",
      },
    };
  }

  return userData;
};
```

I am able to timeout after 10 seconds. Its showing error.message canceled. I need help in catching the Error in Invokecardscreen

Comment: Simply change `return error;` to `return Promise.reject(error)`

Comment: Thanks Phil. What about Invokecardscreen how to catch error over there. Because in the component I need to use if error cancel  do this...

Comment: where i need to make this change, Simply change return error; to return Promise.reject(error)

Comment: _"where i need to make this change"_... in the only place where you currently have `return error;`. _"What about Invokecardscreen how to catch error over there"_... with a [try...catch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch) as indicated you wanted to do

Comment: In API.js: alert(error.message) gives canceled. invokeCardScreen component in case of error cancelled, how to get CardScreenState.response in case of error.

Comment: Please help me how to handle error canceled properly error.response, error.response.data, error.response.status all undefined api.js

Comment: In API.js how to write the generic catch block for Canceled like Network_error.